# I have trouble, j = pygame.joystick.Joystick()

Tags: python, controls, rc, servo

My example code from google.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import pygame
from pygame import
import time
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)

# Initialise the pygame library
pygame.init()

# Connect to the first JoyStick16:11:10:05:0B:1C
j = pygame.joystick.Joystick(0)
j.init()

print 'Initialized Joystick : %s' % j.get_name()

# Setup the various GPIO values, using the BCM numbers for now
MotorA0 = 16
MotorA1 = 18
MotorAE = 22

MotorB0 = 23
MotorB1 = 21
MotorBE = 19
16:11:10:05:0B:1C
A0 = False
A1 = False
B0 = False
B1 = False



GPIO.setup(MotorA0,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(MotorA1,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(MotorAE,GPIO.OUT)

GPIO.setup(MotorB0,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(MotorB1,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(MotorBE,GPIO.OUT)

# Set all the Motors to 'off'
GPIO.output(MotorA0, A0)
GPIO.output(MotorA1, A1)
GPIO.output(MotorAE, False)
GPIO.output(MotorBE, False)
GPIO.output(MotorB0, B0)
GPIO.output(MotorB1, B1)


# Only start the motors when the inputs go above the following threshold
threshold = 0.60


LeftTrack = 0
RightTrack = 0

# Configure the motors to match the current settings.

def setmotors():
    GPIO.output(MotorA0, A0)
    GPIO.output(MotorA1, A1)
    GPIO.output(MotorAE, True)
    GPIO.output(MotorBE, True)
    GPIO.output(MotorB0, B0)
    GPIO.output(MotorB1, B1)

# Try and run the main code, and in case of failure we can stop the motors
try:
    # Turn on the motors
    GPIO.output(MotorAE, True)
    GPIO.output(MotorBE, True)

    # This is the main loop
    while True:

    # Check for any queued events and then process each one
    events = pygame.event.get()
    for event in events:
      UpdateMotors = 0

      # Check if one of the joysticks has moved
      if event.type == pygame.JOYAXISMOTION:
        if event.axis == 1:
          LeftTrack = event.value
          UpdateMotors = 1
        elif event.axis == 3:
          RightTrack = event.value
          UpdateMotors = 1

        # Check if we need to update what the motors are doing
        if UpdateMotors:

          # Check how to configure the left motor

          # Move forwards
          if (RightTrack > threshold):
              A0 = False
              A1 = True
          # Move backwards
          elif (RightTrack < -threshold):
              A0 = True
              A1 = False
          # Stopping
          else:
              A0 = False
              A1 = False

          # And do the same for the right motor
          if (LeftTrack > threshold):
              B0 = False
              B1 = True
          # Move backwards
          elif (LeftTrack < -threshold):
              B0 = True
              B1 = False
          # Otherwise stop
          else:
              B0 = False
              B1 = False

          # Now we've worked out what is going on we can tell the
          # motors what they need to do
          setmotors()


except KeyboardInterrupt:
    # Turn off the motors
    GPIO.output(MotorAE, False)
    GPIO.output(MotorBE, False)
    j.quit()#!/usr/bin/env python

GPIO.cleanup()
```

When i run this code, i have a troubleshoot.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "control.py", line 13, in 
    j = pygame.joystick.Joystick()
TypeError: function takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)

Answer (score 0):

```
Your issue is that the command line j=pygame.joystick.Joystick(0) is calling the first ps3 controller that is available and paired to your raspberry pi (or whatever device you are using). 
With that said, if you do not have a ps3 controller paired with the device, it will never work, because the next command line calls the Ps3controller 0 , and in your case, seems not to be any installed or paired.
```

Also some other issues with your code:

Line 4: Erase this line completely
Line 26: This was suppose to have a # hashtag before it, used only for notation. You can actually delete this line because it was notes from someone else's project anyway.
Line 78: The indentation is incorrect. it has to follow the indentation of the "*while True*" loop above it. So to fix it, make sure to backspace the command in line 78 all the way to the left, then press spacebar 8 times, or press TAB key 2 times, same thing. that will fix it!

Now your code works. actually one last thing, make sure to install pygame library as well, type this in the Xterminal(im using raspberry pi with raspbian) if u don't have it yet: sudo apt-get install python-pygame

I hope this all helped. I know you will have more questions, this code used to piss me off!lol